# Stored procedure with 2 Like parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause, sql-like

I am looking to use a stored procedure to filter my datagridview by either the user entering the part name into txtPartName or MRPID into txtMRPID. However, this is not filtering as expected and just shows all results from the parts table regardless.

I have a feeling this is due to the way I have implemented the AND or perhaps that I can't perform 2 LIKE statements in one procedure perhaps? Anyway can someone point me in the right direction as how to properly perform this procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Parts_ViewAllOrSearch
    @PartNameSearch nvarchar(255),
    @MRPIDSearch nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Parts
    WHERE @PartNameSearch = ''
       OR PartName LIKE '%' + @PartNameSearch + '%'
      AND @MRPIDSearch = ''
       OR MRP_ID LIKE '%' + @MRPIDSearch + '%'
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific,

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need parentheses around the `OR` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM Parts
WHERE 
    (@PartNameSearch = ''  OR  PartName LIKE '%' + @PartNameSearch + '%')
    AND (@MRPIDSearch = '' OR MRP_ID LIKE '%' + @MRPIDSearch + '%')
```

Why you need that is because `AND` has higher logical prescedence than `OR`. So without the parentheses, the `WHERE` clause is equivalent to:

```
WHERE 
    @PartNameSearch = ''  
    OR (PartName LIKE '%' + @PartNameSearch + '%' AND @MRPIDSearch = '')
    OR MRP_ID LIKE '%' + @MRPIDSearch + '%'
```

... which obviously is not what you want.

Finally, please note that, as it stands, your code just does not seem to really these `OR` expressions. If a parameter is the empty string, then, once surrounded with wildcards it will match on all possible values (except `null`  values). You would just write this as:

```
WHERE 
    PartName LIKE '%' + @PartNameSearch + '%'
    AND MRP_ID LIKE '%' + @MRPIDSearch + '%'
```

Comment: This was such a simple fix but your explanation has helped me to better understand how SQL syntax functions. I really appreciate your time to help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes sorry, @GMB was so quick to answer my question that the acceptance was on a 10 minute call down still... talk about efficiency!